# Short cuts to solve Cobb Douglas Utility function (minimization)

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics

Say a Cobb Douglas like:

$$\max_{X,Y\: s.t. X \cdot P_x+ Y \cdot P_y=I} U=X^\alpha Y^\beta$$

When it comes to maximization I would do the following way (for the fastest result):

x: $\alpha/(\alpha + \beta) = r; r*income = r_2$; $r_2$/price good = x$

Is there a similar (or really fast) method to solve for minimization problems?

Comment: What are you minimizing?

Comment: Some restriction or cost, say for exaplme PriceX + PriceY >= budget restriction. A standard Cobb Douglas minimization.

Comment: I coudn't follow your math so I tried to clean it up with latex. Please look and confirm that the updated version is correct.

Comment: I believe you meant maximize utility subject to the constraint. Or did you imply minimize cost subject to utility?

Answer (score 1):

A shortcut to solve $$\min_{x,y} x^{\alpha} y^{\beta}$$ s.t. $$xp_x + yp_x \leq m$$ and $$0 \leq x,y$$ is to set $x = 0$ and/or $y = 0$, as this results in $U(x,y) = 0$, and the function does not map to negative values.